# using font "Consolas" under ubuntu in Sublime_text3

Tags: ubuntu, sublimetext3

I'm used to programing in sublime_text in windows platform, using Consolas font.

Recently, I change my system to Ubuntu, I copy the "Consolas file from "C:\Windows\fonts\" to Linux "/etc/fonts", and I set Sublime_text font's setting, it works, but it looks different from before.

no Italic

please tell me how to handle with it, the sublime_text default font will also be acceptable,

any thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

There are separate `.ttf` files for Consolas Regular, Bold, Bold Italic, and Italic on Windows. To use them on Ubuntu, you'll need to copy all four files to `/etc/fonts`.